# Distribution of Geometric Brownian with time-dependant volatility

Tags: volatility, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, geometric-brownian

The process $S(t) =\exp\left(\mu.t + \int_0^t\sigma(s) \text{d}W(s) - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s)\text{d}s\right)$ where $\sigma(s) = 0.03s$ is log-normally distributed, but i'm not sure about the parameters of this log-normal distribution. Can someone help me to find them ?

Based on this, how can I calculate some probabilities like the following one, for instance : $P[S(15) < 1]$

Thanks for your contributions !

Answer (score 1):

Recognize that the process $S(t)$ is log-normally distributed because it is an exponential of a Gaussian process $X(t)$, in this case $S(t)=e^{X(t)}$.

To find the parameters of the log-normal distribution, you need to calculate the mean and variance of $X(t)$,as the mean and variance of $ln(S(t))$ are those of $X(t)$. We have
$$
E(X(t)) = \mu t - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma^2(s)ds, \quad Var(X(t)) = \int_0^t\sigma^2(s)ds
$$
Substitute $\sigma(s)=0.03s$ and solve.

Now that you know the mean and variance, we can find the probabilities using the log-normal distribution with these parameters. This is done by transforming the problem into a standard normal distribution problem, as the log-normal distribution of $S(t)$ is defined by the normal distribution of $X(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for answering ! But what about the factor $1/2$ ? I guess you forgot it ?

Comment: Is it correct to write that $P[S(15) < 1] = P[e^{X(15)} < 1] = P[X(15) < ln(1)]$ ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot. I updated the answer. And yes, you are correct.

Comment: But when I calculate probabilities like this (for $\mu = 0.04$), I get values near 0. It's weird because it means that there is no risk. I dont understand, I think there is something wrong somewhere ?

Comment: Intuitively, there is risk involved since the volatility is not 0. If you can write out your calculations, I can check your work and we can try and break it down intuitively

Comment: $$S(t) = exp(\mu.t + \int_0^t\sigma(s) \text{d}W(s) - \int_0^t \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s)\text{d}s)$$.
$$ = exp(X(t))\ \text{where} \ X(t) \sim N(0.06t - \frac{(0.01)^{2}t^3}{6}, \frac{(0.01)^{2}t^3}{3})$$
with $\mu = 0.06$ and $\sigma = 0.01t$.
$$P[S(5) < 1] = P[e^{X(5)} < 1]$$
$$= P[X(5) < ln(1)]\ \text{where} \ X(5) \sim N(0.298, 0.0041)$$
$$= P[Z < \frac{ln(1) - 0.298}{\sqrt(0.0041)}]$$
$$= \Phi(-4.65)$$
$$ \simeq 0$$

Comment: Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Intuitively speaking, if we assume log-normal distribution for the stochastic process, with a larger value for the drift compared to the volatility, over a long period of time ($t=5$ years), there is a very small chance of negative returns. In this case, it is a 4 standard deviation event. 

Increase the volatility, or decrease the drift, and you will see how the probability changes.

Comment: Thank you for your help !

Comment: And how can I get the Radon-Nykodym density to go to the "neutral-risk" world ? What about the previous probability in this world ?